# Pass configuration data to a dependency of a angular library using "forRoot"

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-dependency-injection

I've created two Angular libraries, one has the other as a dependency.

the dependency needs to be configured using the forRoot method.
how can i pass the configuration data from the parent library to it's dependency?

for example, let's say we have `TopLevelLib`, which has `OtherLib` as a dependency. OtherLib needs to be passed a configuration object using forRoot.

**End user's AppModule, imports to**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TopLevelLib.forRoot(someConfigData)
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**TopLevelLib - imported to AppModule by the end user**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    OtherLib.forRoot(*****what goes in here?*****)
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...]
})
export class TopLevelLib {
  static forRoot(config: ConfigObj): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [{ provide: SomeInjectionToken, useValue: config }]
    };
  }
}
```

**OtherLib - imported by TopLevelLib**

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  exports: [...]
})
export class OtherLib {
  static forRoot(config: ConfigObj): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [{ provide: SomeInjectionToken, useValue: config }]
    };
  }
}
```

What i need is to pass the configuration object instance from TopLevelLib to OtherLib. So that when the end user configures TopLevelLib using forRoot, OtherLib will be configured with the same data.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `forRoot` parameters typed. You have explicitly defined that `OtherLib` has `config: ConfigObj` as a parameter - that means that the `TopLevelLib` needs to configure it with an instance of `ConfigObj`. So the answer to `*****what goes in here?*****` comment is: an instance of `ConfigObj`.

**Edit**: after comments, you seem to want to pass-through some config value. You can do it this way:

```
export class TopLevelLib {
  static forRoot(config: ConfigObj): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SampleModule,
      providers: [{ provide: ConfigObj, useValue: config }]
    };
  }
}
```

Then the `OtherLib` can use Injector to get this:

```
class OtherLib {
  constructor(@Inject() ConfigObj) {}
...
```

Comment: what i need is to pass the configuration object instance from TopLevelLib to OtherLib. so that when the end user configures TopLevelLib, OtherLib will be configured with the same data.

Comment: i think that because OtherLib is imported to my library from an external source, i need to import it with the config value otherwise the injected object will not be available.

Comment: Well. If you're using the otherlib only in your toplevellib - then only toplevellib imports it and can provide the dependency needed. If you can provide it elsewhere too, and you need this config to be shared, then I guess this should be at the nearest common parent. If the config is per-module-instance, then yeah, something like forRoot. But then maybe do not add the module directly to toplevellib imports - rather in toplevellib.forroot(), return a different, dynamically created module, with otherlib configured as you please as an import.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, i found a good solution. 
I've exposed the injection token used by the service (in the example above, OtherLib),  imported it to the TopLevelLib module, and provided it to the module instance using the forRoot configuration.

Comment: Still not clear for me, can you please share your solution